# Prove Convergence of function series $\sin(nx)e^{-nx}$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm having trouble with this. I need to prove the convergence and the continuity of the convergent function for the function:

$f_n(x) = e^{-nx}\sin(nx)$

And I'm having trouble. I showed that it's less than $\dfrac{e^{-x}}{e-1}$, but... that doesn't help me!

What can I do here to move forward?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointwise, for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$ we have:
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} e^{-nx}\sin(nx) = 0$$
since for any real number $y$ we have $|\sin y|\leq 1$ and for any positive number $n$ we have $\lim_{n\to +\infty}e^{-nx}=0$. The convergence cannot be uniform, since for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have:
$$ f_n\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = \frac{\sin 1}{e}>0. $$
Additionally every $f_n$ belongs to $L^1(\mathbb{R}^+)\cap L^2(\mathbb{R}^+)$ and:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-nx}\sin(nx)\,dx = \frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin z}{e^z}\,dx = \frac{1}{2n},$$
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-2nx}\sin^2(nx)\,dx = \frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2 z}{e^{2z}}\,dz = \frac{1}{8n},$$
so we have convergence to zero with respect to both the $L^1$ and the $L^2$ norm. Now, the condition $|f_n(x)|\leq e^{-nx}$ is enough to grant the the series:
$$ g(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}f_n(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}e^{-nx}\sin(nx) = \text{Im}\sum_{n\geq 1}e^{-n(x-i)} $$
is convergent for any $x>0$. Since the last sum is a geometric series for any $x>0$ we also have:
$$ g(x) = \text{Im}\left(\frac{e^i}{e^x-e^i}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{e^x \sin 1}{1+e^{2x}-2e^x\cos 1}}. $$
<sup>Here $\text{Im}$ stands for the imaginary part of a complex number, $\text{Im}(a+ib)=b$. 

$\text{Im}$ commutes with $\sum$ since it is a linear operator.</sup>

Comment: Oops. This is a function series, not sequence, so it's the sum of the $f_n$s we care about.

Comment: @Paul: ok, I will update the answer, but please try to be clear in the question and state that you are interested in the convergence of the series more than the convergence of the sequence of functions.

Comment: Sorry about that, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Huh. This is a real analysis class and we've had no exposure to Im or i

Comment: @Paul: complex methods are really useful also for some real problems, it is worth to learn this little trick to sum things like $e^{-n}\cos n$ or $e^{-n}\sin n$.

Comment: Any other useful tricks? That one seems useful but I doubt I'm allowed to use it!

Comment: As an alternative, you can expand $\sin(nx)$ as a Taylor series, switch sums and compute $$\sum_{n\geq 1}n^k e^{-nx}$$ for any odd natural number $k$. However, that is a very long road. Better to use the imaginary part trick, believe me.

Comment: Okay, thank you kindly!

Comment: @Paul: To upvote or to accept would be kind, too ;)